# Why my function that creates a pandas dataframe changes the dtype to none when called

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function, dtype

I'm working on processing csv files, I was writing my code without functions and it worked, albeit some problems when trying to fillna with a string, before I did a try and except.
For some reason it didn't work before creating the while loop.
My question is why a dataframe object created inside of a function by reading a csv file name I passed when I called the function, returned an empty object? I thought when the dataframe was in memory it wouldn't be destroyed, what am I missing?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

grossmargin = 1.2

def read_wholesalefile(name):
    mac = name
    apple = pd.read_csv(mac)
    apple['price'] = apple['Wholesale'] * grossmargin
    while True:
        try:
            apple.fillna('N/A', inplace=True)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Not Valid')

    
read_wholesalefile('Wholesalelist5182021.csv')
```

Comment: why don't you actually `return apple` at the end of your method?

Comment: Yes, that's valid too, probably I'm tired, lack of sleep, thanks for pointing that out @JonSG

Answer (score 0):

Well sorry guys, I figure it out by myself:
I was missing the scope, sorry again for the newb stuff. I just started coding in Python a few months ago(last December) and I'm learning in the process.

What worked for me was to add the scope Global, within the function, seriously I didn't know dataframes behaved as variables ... inside a function.

```
#My Modified code that works
import pandas as pd

grossmargin = 1.2

def read_wholesalefile(name):
    global apple
    mac = name
    apple = pd.read_csv(mac)
    apple['price'] = apple['Wholesale'] * grossmargin
    while True:
        try:
            apple.fillna('N/A', inplace=True)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Not Valid')

    
read_wholesalefile('Wholesalelist5182021.csv')
```